# how to copy one index documents to other index in elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch

I created a new index with mappings. 500 000 documents are stored in it.

I want to change the mapping of the index, but it is not possible in elastic search.so I created another index with new new mappings and now I am trying to copy the documents from old index to new index.

I am using scan and scroll type to retrieve the documents from old index and copying to new index.for copying its taking more time and the system is slowing down.

Below is the code that I am using.

```
$client= app('elastic_search');
    $params = [
        "search_type" => "scan",    // use search_type=scan
        "scroll" => "30s",          // how long between scroll requests. should be small!
        "size" => 500000,               // how many results *per shard* you want back
        "index" => "admin_logs422",
        "body" => [
            "query" => [
                "match_all" => []
            ]
        ]
    ];

    $docs = $client->search($params);   // Execute the search

    $scroll_id = $docs['_scroll_id'];   


    while (\true) {

        // Execute a Scroll request
        $response = $client->scroll([
                "scroll_id" => $scroll_id,  //...using our previously obtained _scroll_id
                "scroll" => "500s"           // and the same timeout window
            ]
        );

        if (count($response['hits']['hits']) > 0) {
            foreach($response['hits']['hits'] as $s)
            {

                $params =
                    [
                        'index' => 'admin_logs421',
                        'type' => 'admin_type421',
                        'id'=> $s['_id'],
                        'client' => [
                            'ignore' => [400, 404],
                            'verbose' => true,
                            'timeout' => 10,
                            'connect_timeout' => 10
                        ],
                        'body' => $s['_source']
                    ];

                $response = app('elastic_search')->create($params);

            }


            $scroll_id = $response['_scroll_id'];
        } else {
            // No results, scroll cursor is empty.  You've exported all the data
            return response("completed");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should not have to code stuff like that. There are some excellent tools around to do it for you.

Just look at [Taskrabbit's elasticdump](https://github.com/taskrabbit/elasticsearch-dump) utility which does exactly what you want.

```
elasticdump \
  --input=http://localhost:9200/source_index \
  --output=http://localhost:9200/target_index \
  --type=data
```

Or you can also very easily leverage Logstash as is shown in [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34162468/copy-data-from-one-index-to-another-in-elastic-search/34170586#34170586)

Finally, since you're using Python, you can also use the [elasticsearch-py reindex utility](http://elasticsearch-py.readthedocs.org/en/master/helpers.html#reindex)

Comment: Not working.after copying data from one index to another,no data found in new index

Comment: You've replaced `source_index` by `admin_logs422` and `target_index` by `admin_logs421`, right?

Comment: i have a index admin_logs221  and type admin_type221 with mappings and   30000 documents in it. i created another index with one change in mapping as admin_logs mapping.iam using docker command to  copy data

Comment: docker run --rm -ti elasticdump   --input=http://localhost:9200/admin_logs421   --output=http://localhost:9200/admin_logs422   --type=data  --limit=10000  --bulk=true  --scrollTime=30s

Comment: starting dump
got 10000 objects from source elasticsearch (offset: 0)
sent 10000 objects to destination elasticsearch, wrote 10000
got 570 objects from source elasticsearch (offset: 10000)
sent 570 objects to destination elasticsearch, wrote 570
got 0 objects from source elasticsearch (offset: 10570)
sent 0 objects to destination elasticsearch, wrote 0
Total Writes: 10570
dump complete

Comment: no data is found in the indices..documents didn't transferred.

Comment: And you're sure you have mapped the port 9200 with `-p 9200:9200`?

Comment: where i have to map the port   -p 9200:9200

Answer (score 0):

you can try using the some existing reindexing plugins

https://github.com/codelibs/elasticsearch-reindexing

by sending the following request

```
localhost:9200/{fromindex}/{fromtype}/_reindex/{toindex}/{totype}
```

Comment: getting error when copying data from one index to another

Comment: can you please paste your query and error you have got here

Comment: http://localhost:9200/admin_logs421/admin_type421/_reindex/admin_logs422/admin_type422                                                                                No handler found for uri [/admin_logs421/admin_type421/_reindex/admin_logs422/admin_type422] and method [GET]

Comment: You need to [install the plugin](https://github.com/codelibs/elasticsearch-reindexing) first.