# Elasticsearch - What is the best way to reindex my data without using Logstash or the scroll api?

Tags: elasticsearch, nest, reindex, elasticsearch-1.7.5

I'm using Elasticsearch version 1.7.5. Before I can upgrade to version 2.x (or even 5.x), I need to reindex five large indices so that they conform to the 2.x standards.

Unfortunately, Logstash (and the scroll api) can't reindex my data because of [this problem](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/failed-to-decode-scrollid/43663).

---

My Question:

- What is the best way to reindex my data without using Logstash or the scroll api?

  - If possible, I would prefer to use Nest.

Comment: this answer might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34921637/how-to-copy-one-index-documents-to-other-index-in-elasticsearch/34922623#34922623

Comment: @Val: Thanks. Unfortunately, all of those solutions use the scroll api.

Comment: Would [this doc](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.x/reindex-upgrade.html) helps?

Answer (score 1):

If you're targeting Elasticsearch 5.0+, you can use the [reindex API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-reindex.html#reindex-from-remote) to reindex data from a remote Elasticsearch cluster (the 1.7.5 cluster) into Elasticsearch 5.0+.

NEST 5.x exposes the reindex API as the `ReindexOnServer()` method

```
client.ReindexOnServer(r => r
    .Source(s => s
        .Remote(sr => sr
            // URI to 1.7.5 cluster
            .Host(new Uri("http://localhost:9201"))
        )
        .Index("entries")
    )
    .Destination(d => d
        .Index("entries")
    )
    .WaitForCompletion(true)
);
```

`WaitForCompletion` determines whether the call should wait for reindex to finish. If this is false, the `Task` property on the response can be used to check the status of the operation using the [tasks API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/tasks.html)