# How to natively reuse search results to create a new index?

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a small Elasticsarch service in which I have a few documents. All of them can be retrieved with a

```
GET http://localhost:9200/incident/_doc/_search?size=10000
```

Is there a simple way to reuse the output of this command to feed another ES instance (with the same index name, or another if it is easier)?

My solution would be to write a script which would extract the entries under `hits.hits` and send them to the new ES instance. I am hoping for a native approach, though (where the body of the search result, or part of, would be sent as a `POST`/`PUT` content).

Comment: This answer should help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34922623/4604579

Comment: @Val: oh yes, it does! Thank you. The output from `elasticdump` is actually the list behind `hits.hits`, and it can accept that as an input so this is perfect. I will mark it as a duplicate. Thanks again!